# MySQL #1243 Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am following this [tutorial](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) on my installed version of MySQL, but it's throwing me an error:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(property_name = ''',
      property_name,
      ''', value, NULL)) AS ',
      property_name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  properties;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT item_id, ', @sql, ' FROM properties GROUP BY item_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am pasting it on SQL editor in phpMyAdmin.

I followed the suggestion. No errors shown but here's the result:

```
SELECT item_id
,MAX(IF(property_name = 'color', value, NULL)) AS color
,MAX(IF(property_name = 'size', value, NULL)) AS size
,MAX(IF(property_name = 'weight', value, NULL)) AS weight 
FROM properties GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: instead of executing the last three lines, change it with `SELECT @sql` and post the result here so we can know where the error is.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like actually?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it will execute the query I stated in the update. The output of "@sql" is string.

Comment: Mr A, did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` from your query until after the query runs.

`DEALLOCATE` cancels the statement before it has a chance to run.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a MySQL command-line, I think you'll find your SQL code is fine (as long as `@sql` doesn't equal `NULL`) and the issue is with phpMyAdmin. Another idea is to wrap the code in a stored procedure and then `CALL` the procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). I had the same issue in phpMyAdmin and I tried in Workbench and it works fine.

Comment: thanks, using sequel pro have the same issue with phpMyAdmin but it works fine on Workbench

Comment: I have the same problem using this